# Debouncing in JS causes flickering in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I have a component where debounce is added for the onChange of an input component. This input component only takes numbers as input. While entering decimal value there is a flicker in the component.

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { ProtonInputMoney } from "./ProtonInputMoney;
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

interface IInputMoneyProps {
  value: string;
  onValueChange: (value: string) => void;
  setFocus?: boolean;
  errorMessage?: string;
  infoMessage?: string;
}


const InputMoney: FC<IInputMoneyProps> = ({
  value,
  onValueChange,
  setFocus,
  errorMessage,
  infoMessage,
}) => {
  const maxValue = 999999999.99;

  const handleOnChange = (event: CustomEvent): void => {
    // setError(undefined);
    onValueChange(event.detail);
  };

  const debouncedChangeHandler = debounce(handleOnChange, 300);

  return (
    <div data-testid="input-money" className="flex-1">
      <ProtonInputMoney
        value={value}
        maxValue={maxValue}
        onValueChange={debouncedChangeHandler}
        setFocus={setFocus}
        inputMode="decimal"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputMoney;
```

Why is it so, how can this be corrected?
Please help, thanks!

Below is the code for ProtonInputMoney

```
import { Component, h, Prop, EventEmitter, Host, Event, Listen, Watch, State } from '@stencil/core';
import { isEmptyString, isNumber, notEqualValidator } from '../../utilities/validation-utilities';

const separatorTypeValues = [',', '.'] as const;
export type SeparatorType = typeof separatorTypeValues[number];

export interface IInputMoneyError {
  newValue: string;
  oldValue: string;
  error?: unknown;
}

@Component({
  tag: 'proton-input-money',
  shadow: false,
})
export class ProtonInputMoney {
  initialSelectionStart: number;
  initialSelectionEnd: number;

  inputElementRef!: HTMLInputElement;

  // Storing the previous thousand separated value for easier value comparison
  oldFormattedValue: string = '';

  /**
   * Internal state to add small font class
   */
  @State() showSmall: boolean = false;

  /**
   * Initial placeholder of the input component
   */
  @Prop() placeholder: string = '0';

  /**
   * inputMode to show numeric keypad on mobile
   */
  @Prop() inputMode: string = 'numeric';

  /**
   * isZeroAllowed for the input component
   */
  @Prop() isZeroAllowed: boolean = false;

  /**
   * isDecimalForbidden for the input component
   */
  @Prop() isDecimalForbidden: boolean = false;

  /**
   * Initial value of the input component
   */
  @Prop({ mutable: true }) value: string = '';

  /**
   * Maximum value of the input component
   */
  @Prop() maxValue: number = 999999999.99;

  /**
   * Separator for thousands
   */
  @Prop() thousandSeparator: SeparatorType = ',';

  /**
   * Separator for decimal
   */
  @Prop() decimalSeparator: SeparatorType = '.';

  /**
   * Set focus on input
   */
  @Prop() setFocus: boolean;

  /**
   * Callback for handle error
   */
  @Prop() handleError: (inputMoneyError: IInputMoneyError) => void;

  /**
   * Triggers when input value change
   */
  @Event() valueChange: EventEmitter<string>;

  /**
   * Triggers when a value is pasted into the input
   */
  @Event() valuePaste: EventEmitter<ClipboardEvent>;

  @Watch('thousandSeparator')
  @Watch('decimalSeparator')
  onLocaleChange(newValue: string, oldValue: string): void {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      this.handleSeparatorChange();
    }
  }

  @Watch('setFocus')
  onSetFocus(): void {
    this.shouldSetFocus();
  }

  @Listen('keyup')
  onKeyUpEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const { key, metaKey, ctrlKey } = event;
    const { value } = this.getInputElement(event);
    if (this.invalidKey(metaKey, ctrlKey, key) || this.hasDecimalSeparator(value, key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  }

  @Listen('keydown')
  onKeyDownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = this.getInputElement(event);

    this.initialSelectionStart = selectionStart;
    this.initialSelectionEnd = selectionEnd;
  }

  invalidKey = (metaKey: boolean, ctrlKey: boolean, key: string): boolean => {
    return (
      !this.isActionAllowed(key) &&
      !this.isKeyAllowed(key) &&
      !this.isModifierActionAllowed(metaKey, ctrlKey, key)
    );
  };

  isActionAllowed = (key: string): boolean => {
    const allowedKeys = [
      'backspace',
      'tab',
      'delete',
      'enter',
      'arrowleft',
      'arrowright',
      'arrowup',
      'arrowdown',
      'home',
      'end',
    ];
    return allowedKeys.includes(key.toLowerCase());
  };

  isKeyAllowed = (key: string): boolean => {
    const forbiddenDecimalKeyRegex = new RegExp(`[0-9]`);
    const keyRegex = new RegExp(`[0-9${this.decimalSeparator}]`);
    const regex = this.isDecimalForbidden ? forbiddenDecimalKeyRegex : keyRegex;
    return regex.test(key);
  };

  isModifierActionAllowed = (metaKey: boolean, ctrlKey: boolean, key: string): boolean => {
    const allowedModifierActionKeys = ['a', 'c', 'v', 'x'];
    return (metaKey || ctrlKey) && allowedModifierActionKeys.includes(key.toLowerCase());
  };

  hasDecimalSeparator = (value: string, key: string): boolean => {
    return key === this.decimalSeparator && value.indexOf(key) > 0;
  };

  validateSeparators = (): void => {
    const componentName = 'proton-input-money';
    const thousandSeparatorName = 'thousandSeparator';
    const decimalSeparatorName = 'decimalSeparator';
    notEqualValidator(
      this.thousandSeparator,
      thousandSeparatorName,
      this.decimalSeparator,
      decimalSeparatorName,
      componentName
    );
  };

  getInputElement = (event?: Event): HTMLInputElement => {
    if (!event) {
      return this.inputElementRef;
    }

    const { target } = event;
    return target as HTMLInputElement;
  };

  shouldSetFocus = (): void => {
    if (this.setFocus) {
      const inputElement = this.getInputElement();
      inputElement && inputElement.focus();
      inputElement.selectionStart = -1;
      inputElement.selectionEnd = -1;
    }
  };

  splitByParts = (value: string): string[] => {
    const digitParts = value.split(this.decimalSeparator);
    return [digitParts[0], digitParts[1]];
  };

  deleteWhenCursorOnSeparator = (value: string): string => {
    const newValue = value.split('');
    const oldValue = this.oldFormattedValue.split('');
    if (
      oldValue.length > newValue.length &&
      this.initialSelectionStart === this.initialSelectionEnd &&
      oldValue[this.initialSelectionStart - 1] === this.thousandSeparator
    ) {
      newValue.splice(this.initialSelectionStart - 2, 1);
      return newValue.join('');
    }
    return value;
  };

  padWithDecimal = (value: string): string => {
    if (!isEmptyString(value) && !this.isDecimalForbidden) {
      let [amount, fraction = ''] = this.splitByParts(value);
      const fractionLength = fraction ? fraction.length : 0;
      fraction += Array(Math.max(2 - fractionLength, 0))
        .fill(0)
        .join('');
      return [amount, fraction].join(this.decimalSeparator);
    }
    return value;
  };

  checkValueMoreThanZero = (value: string): string => {
    if (!isEmptyString(value)) {
      let [amount, fraction = ''] = this.splitByParts(value);
      const amountWithoutSeparator = this.removeThousandSeparator(amount);
      const totalAmount = Number(amountWithoutSeparator + fraction);
      const isAllowZeroValue = this.isZeroAllowed && totalAmount === 0;
      if (isAllowZeroValue) {
        return value;
      }
      if (totalAmount <= 0) {
        return '';
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return value;
  };

  removeThousandSeparator = (value: string): string => {
    const thousandSeparatorRegex = new RegExp(`\\${this.thousandSeparator}`, 'g');
    return value.replace(thousandSeparatorRegex, '');
  };

  formatWithThousandSeparator = (value: string): string => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\d(?=(\\d{3})+(?:\\${this.decimalSeparator}\\d*)?$)`, 'g');
    return value.replace(regex, `$&${this.thousandSeparator}`);
  };

  isFractionValid = (fraction: string, fractionInt: number): boolean =>
    fraction ? isNumber(fractionInt) && fraction.length <= 2 && fractionInt <= 99 : true;

  isGreaterThanMaxValue = (amountInt: number, fractionInt: number): boolean => {
    let totalAmount = amountInt;
    if (fractionInt) {
      const fractionFloat = fractionInt / 100;
      totalAmount += fractionFloat;
    }

    return totalAmount > this.maxValue;
  };

  validateInput = (newValue: string, oldValue: string): string => {
    if (isEmptyString(newValue)) {
      return '';
    }

    if (newValue === this.decimalSeparator) {
      return `0${this.decimalSeparator}`;
    }

    const valueWithoutSeparator = this.removeThousandSeparator(newValue);
    const [amount, fraction] = this.splitByParts(valueWithoutSeparator);
    const amountInt = Number(amount);
    const fractionInt = fraction ? Number(fraction) : undefined;

    if (
      !isNumber(amountInt) ||
      !this.isFractionValid(fraction, fractionInt) ||
      this.isGreaterThanMaxValue(amountInt, fractionInt)
    ) {
      if (this.handleError) {
        this.handleError({ newValue, oldValue });
      }
      return oldValue;
    }

    return [amountInt.toString(), fraction].filter((it) => it !== undefined).join(this.decimalSeparator);
  };

  setElementValue = (element: HTMLInputElement, value: string): void => {
    element.value = this.formatWithThousandSeparator(value);
  };

  setElementCursor = (element: HTMLInputElement, event?: Event): void => {
    const newFormattedValue = element.value;
    if (!event || (event && event.type !== 'blur')) {
      const lengthDiff = newFormattedValue.length - this.oldFormattedValue.length;
      const endCursorPosition = this.initialSelectionEnd + lengthDiff;

      element.selectionStart = endCursorPosition;
      element.selectionEnd = endCursorPosition;
    }

    this.oldFormattedValue = newFormattedValue;
  };

  shouldRenderSmallFont = (valueWithoutSeparator: string): void => {
    const [amount, fraction] = this.splitByParts(valueWithoutSeparator);
    const amountLength = amount ? amount.length : 0;
    const fractionLength = fraction ? fraction.length : 0;
    this.showSmall = amountLength + fractionLength > 8;
  };

  handleInputChange = (newValue: string, oldValue: string): string => {
    this.value = this.validateInput(newValue, oldValue);
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    return this.value;
  };

  applyElementChanges = (
    newValue: string,
    element: HTMLInputElement = this.getInputElement(),
    event?: Event
  ): void => {
    this.setElementValue(element, newValue);
    this.setElementCursor(element, event);
  };

  updateInputElementValue = (
    newValue: string,
    oldValue: string,
    element?: HTMLInputElement,
    event?: Event
  ): void => {
    const nextValue = this.handleInputChange(newValue, oldValue);
    this.applyElementChanges(nextValue, element, event);
    this.shouldRenderSmallFont(nextValue);
  };

  handleOnInput = (event: InputEvent): void => {
    const inputElement = this.getInputElement(event);
    const { value } = inputElement;

    const updatedValue = this.deleteWhenCursorOnSeparator(value);
    this.updateInputElementValue(updatedValue, this.value, inputElement, event);
  };

  handleOnBlur = (event: FocusEvent): void => {
    const inputElement = this.getInputElement(event);
    const { value } = inputElement;

    const zeroPaddedValue = this.padWithDecimal(value);
    const moreThanZeroValue = this.checkValueMoreThanZero(zeroPaddedValue);
    this.updateInputElementValue(moreThanZeroValue, this.value, inputElement, event);
  };

  handleSeparatorChange = (): void => {
    this.validateSeparators();
    this.updateInputElementValue(this.value, '');
  };

  handleOnPaste = (event: ClipboardEvent): void => {
    this.valuePaste.emit(event);
  };

  // Modifying value on will load to avoid additional render cycle
  componentWillLoad() {
    this.validateSeparators();

    const zeroPaddedValue = this.padWithDecimal(this.value);
    this.handleInputChange(zeroPaddedValue, '');
    this.shouldRenderSmallFont(this.value);
  }

  // Apply changes to value only after element loaded
  componentDidLoad() {
    this.applyElementChanges(this.value);
    this.shouldSetFocus();
  }

  // Updating input value when value changes
  componentWillUpdate() {
    const oldValue = this.removeThousandSeparator(this.oldFormattedValue);
    if (this.value !== oldValue) {
      const validatedValue = this.validateInput(this.value, oldValue);
      this.setElementValue(this.getInputElement(), validatedValue);
      this.oldFormattedValue = this.getInputElement().value;
      this.shouldRenderSmallFont(validatedValue);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const formInputClasses = {
      'proton-form-input': true,
      'proton-form-input--money': true,
      ['proton-form-input--placeholder']: this.isZeroAllowed,
    };
    const inputClasses = {
      'proton-input': true,
      'proton-input--small': this.showSmall,
    };

    return (
      <Host class={formInputClasses}>
        <input
          ref={(el) => {
            this.inputElementRef = el;
          }}
          class={inputClasses}
          type="text"
          placeholder={this.placeholder}
          inputmode={this.inputMode}
          onInput={this.handleOnInput}
          onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
          onPaste={this.handleOnPaste}
        />
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

The InputMoney component internally calls ProtonInputMoney, added it for reference.

Comment: is your debounce function working as expected?

Comment: @RaviYadav yes it is.

Comment: are there any events associated with `onValueChange` ? Could you share the code from where InputMoney is being called?